# does IS LIST works with @sys.any in dialogflow fulfillment?

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Is it possible to use IS LIST with @sys.any

I have checked the IS LIST for games and language and IS LIST works well with language because it takes input as @sys.language and gives me different languages given by user, but games takes input as @sys.any

```
example-
Bot: which language do you know?
User: English, French and Chinese
Bot: Your favorite games?
User: Cricket, Football and Chess
```

responses In case of Language

```
"parameters": {
      "langName": [
        "English",
        "French",
        "Chinese",
      ],
```

responses In case of Games

```
"parameters": {
      "games": "Cricket, Football and Chess",
```

How to get different values in case of Games as getting in language.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to use lists with `@sys.any` because, literally, anything and everything matches it, including the separators.

In order to create a list of games, you will need to create an Entity Type of `Games` and include the list of games you accept in it.